# Cannot Select a Temporary table's Column?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

Seems I cannot select the temporary table's column by the column name it inherits from the views I'm selecting from. I get the error: "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetConsolidatedData, Line 44 [Batch Start Line 0]
Invalid column name 'comp_id'."

```
select * 
into #tmp0
from Competitor_View
where [Competitor Name] like @competitor_name;

select * 
into #tmp1
from #tmp0
where [Competitor Part Number] like @competitor_part;

select * 
into #CustomerResult
from #tmp1
where [Koyo Part Number] like @koyo_part;

--------------

select * 
into #tmp3
from Customer_View
where [Customer Name] like @customer_name;

select * 
into #tmp4
from #tmp3
where [Customer Part Number] like @customer_part;

select * 
into #CompetitorResult
from #tmp4
where [Koyo Part Number] like @koyo_part;

--everything after this fails
select 
#CompetitorResult.comp_id,
#CompetitorResult.[Competitor Part Number], 
#CompetitorResult.[Competitor Comment], 
#CompetitorResult.[Competitor Name], 
#CompetitorResult.[Koyo Part Number] as [Associated Koyo Part Number],
#CustomerResult.cust_id, 
#CustomerResult.[Customer Part Number], 
#CustomerResult.[Customer Comment], 
#CustomerResult.[Customer Name] 
from #CompetitorResult
join #CustomerResult
on #CompetitorResult.[Koyo Part Number] = #CustomerResult.[Koyo Part Number];
```

I know I've got the right name for the column because running the following confirms that:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CompetitorResult')
```

Comment: All these `select * into #temptables` are they absolutely necessary?? I doubt it very much though....

Comment: And what does `select * from #CompetitorResult join #CustomerResult on #CompetitorResult.[Koyo Part Number] = #CustomerResult.[Koyo Part Number];` return?

Answer (score 2):

Your Query should look something like this... (without any temp tables)

```
select  cp.comp_id
       ,cp.[Competitor Part Number]
       ,cp.[Competitor Comment]
       ,cp.[Competitor Name]
       ,cp.[Koyo Part Number] as [Associated Koyo Part Number]
       ,cu.cust_id
       ,cu.[Customer Part Number]
       ,cu.[Customer Comment]
       ,cu.[Customer Name] 
from Competitor_View cp
INNER JOIN Customer_View cu ON cp.[Koyo Part Number] = cu.[Koyo Part Number]
where cp.[Koyo Part Number] like @koyo_part
  AND cp.[Competitor Part Number] like @competitor_part
  AND cp.[Competitor Name] like @competitor_name
  AND cu.[Customer Name] like @customer_name
  AND cu.[Customer Part Number] like @customer_part
  AND cu.[Koyo Part Number] like @koyo_part
```

Comment: So it needs to know the view to make the columns selectable by their names when dealing with temporary tables?

Comment: After seeing this query I'll never write a query the way I did before again.

Comment: While I agree this is the most correct SQL, I think it's also somewhat beside the point of the question.  Assuming `Competitor_View.comp_id` exists, the code in the given question should not error.

Comment: @BaconBits this platform's protocol is to give the best solution for a problem, To provide a working poor solution violates this protocol. hence the better approach to the whole problem. cheers.

Comment: @M.Ali True, but my point is that I wouldn't say, "You're doing it wrong; do it this way," because we don't know what every user who searches for these terms is doing.  And, I mean, can you explain *why* OP's listed code doesn't work?  I can't.  Yes, it's a poor solution to a problem as simple as the one he or she appears to have, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't work, nor that every usage of "nested" temp tables is a bad solution.  The code *should* work.  *Why* doesn't it?  That's the real question to answer.